# The Strength of the Decision in Decision Tree

Tags: cart, rpart

I learn how to use decision tree in R

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
asRules(fit)
```

return,

```
Rule number: 3 [Kyphosis=present cover=19 (23%) prob=0.58]
   Start< 8.5

 Rule number: 23 [Kyphosis=present cover=7 (9%) prob=0.57]
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Age>=55
   Age< 111

 Rule number: 22 [Kyphosis=absent cover=14 (17%) prob=0.14]
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Age>=55
   Age>=111

 Rule number: 10 [Kyphosis=absent cover=12 (15%) prob=0.00]
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Age< 55

 Rule number: 4 [Kyphosis=absent cover=29 (36%) prob=0.00]
   Start>=8.5
   Start>=14.5
```

If I want to make a plot of decision tree, I use the following:

```
library(rattle)
fancyRpartPlot(fit)
```

return me the following figure which is associated with the rules above.
[image]

My question is that

what does `prob` in each rule mean ?
I am confused because when the decision of rule number 22 is `absent` the `prob = 0.14`.
I think it should be `prob = 0.86` since the number indicates how strong of this decision will be `absent`.

Could anyone clarify on this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `prob` always means how likely the patient is to be `present`, even if the node itself is going to predict `absent`. A probability of `0.14` that kyphosis is present corresponds to a probability of `1 - 0.14 = 0.86` that kyphosis is absent.